# Best way to do flattening of nested getter result inside getter

Tags: c++, range-v3

sometimes I have the task of finding if some nested getter inside a value returned by getter has some property.
classic c++ would be something like:

```
for (const auto& label: labels) 
  for (const auto& artist: label.artists()) 
    if (artist.name = "Arcade Fire")
       return true;
return false;
```

What is the best way to do this with ranges? 
I think something like this may work:

```
 labels|  transform (&Label::artists) | join | transform(&Artist::name) | join | find_if_fn([](){/*...*/}) ;
```

But it is quite long, (partially because instead of .member_fn you must write Class:member_fn. 
Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: No answer, because I don't know range-v3 (except [link](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) ), but the inner loop in the input example can be replaced with std::find_if, so I guess that only one join is needed to flatten all artists, so there names can be checked.  Also, the find_if_fn() lambda could get the name, so the second transform isn't needed anymore, something like `labels |  transform (&Label::artists) | join | find_if_fn([](const Artist& a){ return a.name == "The Smiths";});`. Does this actually make any sense?

Comment: yeah, I could have used std::find_if, but in my code i prefer no to mix for and std::some_alg.

Comment: just to clarify when there is an option between for and std:: alg i pick alg, i just don tlike mixing them.

Comment: I meant this in a conceptual way to arrive at my range-v3 attempt.  Although I don't have a problem with using algorithms with loops myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
using namespace ranges;
auto rng = labels | view::transform(&Label::artists) | view::join;
return find(rng, "Arcade Fire", &Artist::name) != end(rng);
```

gets the job done in a fairly straightforward way. A `view::filter` formulation:

```
using namespace ranges;
auto rng = labels | view::transform(&Label::artists) | view::join |
    view::filter([](const Artist& a){ return a.name() == "Arcade Fire"; });
return !empty(rng);
```

Is a bit wordier, but probably has similar performance. It's also fairly clear how to generalize it from "Is there a foo?" to "Return all of the foos."